# Conditional setInterval & clearInterval in ReactJS + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, setinterval, clearinterval

In single page web app, city's map rendered with traffic layer.
Currently, working on a live mode switch, which if ON should update the traffic layer on map every 5 minutes.
When live mode is switched off, the 5 minute timer should go off.

For this requirement, got hints for two options from few blogs & posts.
1. Javascript methods: setInterval and clearInterval
2. Use of web sockets

Since this web app has only couple of users besides lack of knowledge for web sockets, decided to go with the first option.
However, faced difficulty in successful execution of clearInterval() when switch goes to off mode.
In the code below, 'timeout' value passed to clearInterval is always undefined.

```
const handleOkBtnClick = (): void => {
    let timeout;
    if(live){
          timeout = setInterval(updateFilter, 60000);
          console.log('live ON == '+ timeout); // prints number like 89 or 146
        }else{
          console.log('live Off == '+ timeout); //always prints 'undefined' 
          clearInterval(timeout);           
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like conditional execution of setInterval and clearInterval isn't an option.
Jumping in to javascript development after a decade, What am I missing?
Any suggestion for alternative approach will be appriciated.
Using ReactJS v16.11, Typescript v3.7

Comment: You have problem with scope here,  your `let timeout` is only ever scoped to this function, you need to push it up somewhere more global to this component.  eg.. maybe try `this.timeout = ` etc.

Comment: `timeout` is not part of the app state, it is defined and assigned on every click, and it is `undefined` in your `clearInterval`, isn't it? It should be defined in a higher scope.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Variable scope is of course one of the issue in the code. I 've tried the suggestion but unable to satisfy Typescript with eslint rules . The error thrown are mostly related to type of timeout variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [timeout, setTimeout] = useState(0);  
const handleOkBtnClick = (): void => {

    if(live){      
      setTimeout(window.setInterval(updateFilter, 60000));
      console.log('timeout == '+ timeout);
    }else{
      console.log('clearInterval == '+ timeout); 
      clearInterval(timeout);          
    }
}
```

This code is working without any warning or error.
But, pros and cons of using window.setInterval Vs. setInterval if any, should be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `timeout` variable is defined within `handleOkBtnClick` so whenever this function is called, the timeout value is reset to undefined and if live is true, its set to timerId

The solution here is to move the timer to a class variable

```
class TrafficLights extends React.Component {
   timeout = null
   ...
   handleOkBtnClick = (): void => {
    if(live){
          this.timeout = setInterval(updateFilter, 60000);
          console.log('live ON == '+ this.timeout); // prints number like 89 or 146
        }else{
          console.log('live Off == '+ this.timeout); 
          clearInterval(this.timeout);           
        }
     }
   }
   ...
}
```

Now it looks like you use functional component, so you can store the timeout in a `useRef` if you use react-hooks

```
const TrafficLights = () =>   {
   const timeout = useRef<number | null>(null);
    ...
     const handleOkBtnClick = (): void => {
        if(live){
              timeout.current = window.setInterval(updateFilter, 60000);
              console.log('live ON == '+ timeout.current); // prints number like 89 or 146
            }else{
              console.log('live Off == '+ timeout.current); 
              clearInterval(timeout.current);           
            }
         }
       }
      ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham for providing immediate response. I 've tried both the solutions suggested. Yes, React FC is being used. However, had issue with timeout variable declaration with respect to it's return type. <Timeout> is not available as return type for setInterval.  NodeJs.Timeout type is internally created and returned on setInterval use. Not allowed to  declare and initialize it with 0 or null. I guess due to typescript and eslint rules.

Comment: As per the [link](https://guillaume.vanderest.org/posts/typescript-timer-number/) would it be legitimate to use window.setInterval() method? It's return type is number. It's easy to declare/initialize even with usage of useState hook.

Comment: Yes, you could use window,setInterval as it provides the return type as number and also define the useRef to be of number